# Second order ODE solution coefficients, complex eigenvalue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been stuck by a problem. The equation is $y'' = \lambda y$. I know the solution will be in the form of $y=c_1 e^{\alpha x}+ c_2 e^{-\alpha x}$,
given $\lambda=\alpha^2$.

Now, is it true that when the real part of $\alpha$ is larger than 0, $c_1=0$?
We can also write the solution as (for $\alpha=a+bi$):
$$
\begin{split}
y &= c_1 e^{ax}(\cos(bx)+i\sin(bx))+ c_2 e^{ax}(\cos(bx)-i\sin(bx)) \\
  &= (c_1+c_2) e^{ax} \cos(bx) + i(c_1-c_2) e^{ax} \sin(bx)
\end{split}
$$

But I cannot see why $c_1=0$ when $a>0$?

Comment: Your solution is incorrect. It should be $y=c_1\,e^{\lambda x}+c_2\,e^{-\lambda x}.$

Comment: @AdrianKeister yes, typo, thank you!

Comment: Your statement is missing a demand on the solution, there is no reason to expect $c_1=0$ for any general solution. As you talk about the real part and not about initial conditions, there is perhaps a demand that the solution be bounded for $x\in[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Yes! So that’s why? If $c_1$ is not 0 then the solution will not be bounded because of the exponential part?

Comment: Even you have $c_1=0$ it won't be bounded. Because the positive expoenntial is still there